# Error message when running jobs using torque. read_tcp_reply, Mismatching protocols. Expected protocol 4 but read reply for 0

Tags: pbs, torque

My system is Cent OS7 and I installed `torque-6.1.0`  configuring with `./configure --prefix=/opt/pbs --with-debug --with-scp --disable-gcc-warnings`

My server name is "node00" and I added a slave node called "node01"

```
[root@node00 torque]# pbsnodes
node01
     state = free
     power_state = Running
     np = 16
     ntype = cluster
     status = opsys=linux,uname=Linux node01 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64,nsessions=0,nusers=0,idletime=7057,totmem=98382176kb,availmem=97993700kb,physmem=32846184kb,ncpus=16,loadave=0.00,gres=,netload=286314300,state=free,varattr= ,cpuclock=Fixed,macaddr=0c:c4:7a:02:ba:98,version=6.1.0,rectime=1481028058,jobs=
     mom_service_port = 15002
     mom_manager_port = 15003
```

I submitted a simple job `echo "sleep 5" | qsub`
and then it returned an error message in `qstat -f`

```
queue_type = E
sched_hint = Unable to copy files back - please see the mother superior's
    log for exact details.
comment = Job started on Tue Dec 06 at 21:35
```

So I read the mother superior's log `vi /var/spool/torque/mom_logs/20161206`

```
12/06/2016 21:35:33.397;02;   pbs_mom.14693;Svr;Log;Log opened
12/06/2016 21:35:33.397;02;   pbs_mom.14693;Svr;pbs_mom;Torque Mom Version = 6.1.0, loglevel = 0
12/06/2016 21:35:33.404;02;   pbs_mom.14693;Svr;setpbsserver;node00
12/06/2016 21:35:33.404;02;   pbs_mom.14693;Svr;mom_server_add;server node00 added
12/06/2016 21:35:33.405;02;   pbs_mom.14694;n/a;initialize;independent
12/06/2016 21:35:33.405;02;   pbs_mom.14694;Svr;dep_initialize;mom is now oom-killer safe
12/06/2016 21:35:33.405;02;   pbs_mom.14694;Svr;read_mom_hierarchy;No local mom hierarchy file found, will request from server.
12/06/2016 21:35:33.407;128;   pbs_mom.14694;Svr;pbs_mom;before init_abort_jobs
12/06/2016 21:35:33.410;02;   pbs_mom.14694;Svr;pbs_mom;Is up
12/06/2016 21:35:33.410;02;   pbs_mom.14694;Svr;setup_program_environment;MOM executable path and mtime at launch: /opt/pbs/sbin/pbs_mom 1481027487
12/06/2016 21:35:33.414;02;   pbs_mom.14694;Svr;pbs_mom;Torque Mom Version = 6.1.0, loglevel = 0
12/06/2016 21:35:33.419;01;   pbs_mom.14706;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::read_tcp_reply, Mismatching protocols. Expected protocol 4 but read reply for 0
12/06/2016 21:35:33.419;01;   pbs_mom.14706;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::read_tcp_reply, Could not read reply for protocol 4 command 4: End of File
12/06/2016 21:35:33.419;01;   pbs_mom.14706;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::mom_server_update_stat, Couldn't read a reply from the server
12/06/2016 21:35:33.419;01;   pbs_mom.14706;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::send_update_to_a_server, Could not contact any of the servers to send an update
12/06/2016 21:35:33.419;01;   pbs_mom.14706;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::send_update_to_a_server, Status not successfully updated for 1 MOM status update intervals
12/06/2016 21:36:18.445;01;   pbs_mom.14795;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::read_tcp_reply, Mismatching protocols. Expected protocol 4 but read reply for 0
12/06/2016 21:36:18.445;01;   pbs_mom.14795;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::read_tcp_reply, Could not read reply for protocol 4 command 4: End of File
12/06/2016 21:36:18.445;01;   pbs_mom.14795;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::mom_server_update_stat, Couldn't read a reply from the server
12/06/2016 21:36:18.445;01;   pbs_mom.14795;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::send_update_to_a_server, Could not contact any of the servers to send an update
12/06/2016 21:36:18.445;01;   pbs_mom.14795;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::send_update_to_a_server, Status not successfully updated for 2 MOM status update intervals
```

It seems like `node01` and  `node00` can't send data each other. Is it right? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Things to to check: confirm the server and compute are the same version. Verify that you don't have extra pbs_mom processes running. Disable ipchains and iptables on both the server and the node. Increase $loglevel in mom_priv/config, restart pbs_mom, and then check the mom's log and syslog.

Comment: What you mentioned check lists done correctly. I installed lower torque version then the error messages are more kindly like `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)`. It looks like ssh-permission problem. But i installed this version with `./configure --with-rcp=/usr/bin/rcp` then why my torque still want to use `ssh`? ..

Comment: Anyway.. I generated authorized keys then it run well. But it still confusing me why `torque` doesn't use `rsh`. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the headline text:  **"read_tcp_reply, Mismatching protocols. Expected protocol 4 but read reply for 0"**
This is an error that shows on systems when:

1. pbs_mom runs on a node unknown to the pbs_server (excluded from the nodes file)
2. When the /var/spool/torque/server_priv/jobs directory get clogged with job files that should have been removed on job termination (this can easily grow to thousands of files as pbs_server is notoriously bad doing cleanup). Same thing applies for /var/spool/torque/server_priv/arrays directory.
3. Clearing the above two situations it is still seen on a system with 400 nodes and 1000 jobs (queued and/or running). In this case it happens 5-10 times an hour.

In all cases tcpdump shows on the pbs_server side that the mom is sent a tcp reset after it sent a status update. It is easily traced with:

```
    tcpdump -i <interface> tcp port 15001 and tcp[13]=4

    08:15:25.162128 IP 10.44.0.94.15001 > 10.44.1.220.215: Flags [R], seq 2437471647, win 0, length 0

On the node this is logged:
    10/13/2018 08:15:25.161;01; pbs_mom.17548;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::read_tcp_reply, Mismatching protocols. Expected protocol 4 but read reply for 0
    10/13/2018 08:15:25.161;01;   pbs_mom.17548;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::read_tcp_reply, Could not read reply for protocol 4 command 4: End of File
    10/13/2018 08:15:25.161;01;   pbs_mom.17548;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::mom_server_update_stat, Couldn't read a reply from the server
    10/13/2018 08:15:25.161;01;   pbs_mom.17548;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::send_update_to_a_server, Could not contact any of the servers to send an update
    10/13/2018 08:15:25.161;01;   pbs_mom.17548;Svr;pbs_mom;LOG_ERROR::send_update_to_a_server, Status not successfully updated for 1 MOM status update intervals
```

UPDATE:
We finally solved the problem by implementing MOM hierarchy in the file /var/spool/torque/server_priv/mom_hierarchy.
For a 500 node cluster we defined 8 groups (path in mom_hierarchy) with a top level of 2 nodes and one level with the rest of the nodes in that group. Something like this:

```
<path>
<level>node1,node2</level>
<level> comma separated list of some 60 nodes</level>
</path>
<path> 
<level>node2,node1</level>
<level comma separated list of some 60 nodes</level>
</path>
<path>
<level>node3,node4</level>
<level>comma separated list of some 60 nodes</level>
</path>
<path>
<level>node4,node3</level>
<level>comma separated list of some 60 nodes</level>
</path>
.....
```